# Restrict the input characters in textfield / numberfield using regular expression?

Tags: regex, validation, extjs

I use numberField in ExtJS Form and want to enter only positive numbers, in range of 0-99 and it should accept only 2 characters (and not more than 2).

```
{
    xtype:"textfield",
    allowNegative: false,
    allowDecimals: false,
    minValue: 0,
    maxValue: 99,
    maxLength: 2
}
```

gives an error in above code but it is accepting more then 2 characters.

I also tried below but issue is same:

```
{
    xtype:"textfield",
    regex: /^\d{0,2}$/,
    regexText: "<b>Error</b></br>Invalid Number entered.",
    validator: function(v) {
        return /^\d{0,2}$/.test(v)?true:"Invalid Number";
    }
}
```

How to restrict to input more then 2 characters?

Comment: That is a total joke, we must google how to set maxLength (a HTML simple property) in EXT. That framework is a joke.

Comment: Right, it is joke but it has different syntax also available. but this is not good we should use different syntax.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

if you're using version 3, the [TextField](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/docs/?class=Ext.form.TextField)'s `maxLength` documentation describes using the `autoCreate` property to state the maximum length (the doc example shows a NumberField but it is also supported by the TextField class):

> maxLength : Number Maximum input field length allowed by validation
>   (defaults to Number.MAX_VALUE). This behavior is intended to provide
>   instant feedback to the user by improving usability to allow pasting
>   and editing or overtyping and back tracking. To restrict the maximum
>   number of characters that can be entered into the field use autoCreate
>   to add any attributes you want to a field, for example:

```
var myField =
new Ext.form.NumberField({
     id: 'mobile',
     anchor:'90%',
     fieldLabel: 'Mobile',
     maxLength: 16, // for validation
     autoCreate: {tag: 'input', type: 'text', size: '20', autocomplete:
'off', maxlength: '10'} });
```

Using version 4, a TextField has the [`enforceMaxLength`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-enforceMaxLength) property.

If you're set on using a regex, both versions support the `maskRe` property, although I don't think this prevents invalid values that are pasted.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I also do it with differently

Comment: +1 for turning me on to a new feature. Since its release, I've been trying to learn all the ins and outs of 4, and boy are there a lot. Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if vtype was there before ExtJS 4.x but this is how you can use vtype.

```
var validMileRadius = /^([0-9]{1,4})/;
        Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
            //  vtype validation function
            radius: function(val, field) {
                return validMileRadius.test(val);
            },
        radiusText: 'Not a Valid Radius.'
    });

{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    width: 40,
    maxLength : 4,
    style : {marginLeft:'10px'},
    id : 'cityRadius',
    enforceMaxLength :4,
    vtype : 'radius'                    
}
```

Thanks
Punith

Answer (score 4):

FOR EVERYBODY, WHO STUCK ON THE SAME

For ExtJS 4.x You even don't need to create VType. From ExtJS 4.x documentation for `Ext.form.field.Number`:

```
enforceMaxLength : Boolean
True to set the maxLength property on the underlying input field. Defaults to false
```

So, You just have to specify maxLength and set enforceMaxLength to true. According on previous post it might look like this:

```
{
  xtype: 'textfield',
  width: 40,
  maxLength : 4,,
  enforceMaxLength : true  
  style : {marginLeft:'10px'},
  id : 'cityRadius'                
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a helper, but to restrict a textfield to allow only numbers you can set the properties of the text field with the attribute "maskRe". It allows you to create masks with regular expressions. Here is a mask that allows you to enter only the numbers:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Text Field(numbers-only)',
    enforceMaxLength:true,  //Restrict typing past maxLength: n
    maxLength: 8,           //Set max length validation
    maskRe:/[0-9.]/         //Allow only numbers
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
maxLength: 2,
enforceMaxLength: true,
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically setting the maxLength, I came up with this override:

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.field.Number, {
  /**
   * Setter: this method will set the maxLength variable on our NumberField
   * class, and on its actual dom element, so we can actually restrict the user
   * from entering over the maxLength
   * @param {Number} maxLength
   */
  setMaxLength: function(maxLength) {
    this.maxLength = maxLength;
    var inputEl = this.inputEl;
    if (inputEl) {
      var domEl = inputEl.dom;
      if (domEl) {
        domEl.maxLength = maxLength;
      }
    }
  },

  /**
   * Shortcut method for setting the maxLength based on the maxValue... if
   * maxValue is not set, then 0 is used, which means the maxLength will be 1
   */
  setMaxLengthFromMaxValue: function() {
    var maxValue = this.maxValue || 0;
    if (maxValue >= 0) {
      this.setMaxLength(maxValue.toString().length);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple use maskre config to restrict textfield.
if will allows you to enter just numbers & alphabets.

```
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Text Field(numbers-only)',
    enforceMaxLength:true,
    maxLength: 8,
    maskRe: /[A-Za-z0-9]/
```