# Regular Expression for European Currency Input in ExtJS 4.2

Tags: javascript, regex, extjs, extjs4.2

I have a textfield in which user will enter the price value. I have to take input as 0,00 (No decimal only one comma for the value of cents). 
So User can enter following

- 123
- 123, (I will remove this comma in Blur Event)
- 123,1
- 123,11

So I wrote this RegExp: ^\d+(,\d{0,2})?$ and tested it on [regexpal.com](http://www.regexpal.com/) for the above test cases and it verified all of them.

Now when I am using this in my code as

```
xtype:'textfield',
fieldLabel: 'Tiefbau(informativ)',
maskRe: /^\d+(,\d{0,2})?$/
```

And try to enter value 123,12, it doesn't allow me to enter **comma** because I found that Textfield compare each individual character with the "maskRe" expression.

I want **"One Or No Comma"** and **"No Decimal Point"**
Can anyone tell me a solution for this or point out my mistake?

Comment: Could you please show all the relevant code? Are you sure you did not change the regex from the one you are actually using? How are you using the regex?

Comment: @stribizhev My entire code for Textfield is written above. I checked the value of maskRe by listening change evenet of the text, and it remain same. 
Is it possible that Textfield compare each entered character individually?

Comment: I do not think so, please give me some more minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the **numberfield** component which derives of **textfield**?
It is a specialised input field for numbers which allow only numeric input to be entered.

When you look in the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Number) you will see that it solves your problem with the comma instead of dot with the `decimalSeparator` config.

With the `minValue` and `decimalPrecision` config you should have an input field which fits your needs.

```
{
    xtype: 'numberfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Tiefbau(informativ)',

    decimalSeparator: ',',   // use comma instead of dot
    minValue: 0,             // prevents negative numbers
    decimalPrecision: 2,     // maximum precision to display after the decimal separator
    allowExponential: false, // disallow exponential values ([e+-] chars not typable)

    // Remove spinner buttons, and arrow key and mouse wheel listeners
    hideTrigger: true,
    keyNavEnabled: false,
    mouseWheelEnabled: false
}
```

See the [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/13f8).

Comment: This is definitely a better and proper approach. Although I fixed my problem by handling this comparison in the change event of the textfield(Posted in my answer), but this is what I needed in the first place. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `?` quantifier with the comma:

```
/^\d+,?\d{0,2}$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wI3hQ1/1)

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `,?` - one or zero commas
- `\d{0,2}` - zero, one or two digits
- `$` - end of string

Use it [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/6747ogyL/1/), e.g.:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    title: 'User Form',
    height: 75,
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [
        {
           xtype:'textfield',
           name: 'name',
           fieldLabel: 'Tiefbau(informativ)',
           validator: function (val) {
               var tr = /^\d+,?\d{0,2}$/.test(val),
                 errMsg = "Must be a valid number";
               return tr ? true : errMsg;
           }
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: I think the problem is not with the regex [`/^\d+(,\d{0,2})?$/`](https://regex101.com/r/wI3hQ1/2) should work.

Comment: Another way of using the pattern in extjs can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10089803/3832970).

Comment: @stribizhev Thank you for your response. Your expression is working exactly like mine. 
I tested the validator function thing, but is there a way which just prevent user from entering wrong value? Cause once the value will be entered I will process it right away so I can't take the risk by allowing user to enter anything wrong.

Comment: I have come up with something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6747ogyL/1/). You can use a [validator](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-validator) to actually run a regex check.

Answer (score 0):

Answer which I have accepted is perfect. Another solution which I made was to listen to change event of the textfield and doing this:

```
change: function(thiss, newValue, oldValue, eOpts ){

    var regX = (/^(\d+(,\d{0,2})?$)/gm).test(newValue);

    if(regX == false ){

      if(newValue == "")
        thiss.setValue("");
      else
        thiss.setValue(oldValue);   
    }
}
```

It will allow user to enter anything but if user's new value is not according to RegExp than it will replace the new value with the old Known value.